# Photoshop Keyboard shortcut for last brush used

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a Photoshop keyboard shortcut for last brush used? The internet is tellig me that "Shift + ‘,’ or ‘.’ moves to the first/last brush in the list" but when I do this it changes the mode from 'Normal' to 'Luminosity'.

**EDIT** - What seems to be happening is that after learning about using the comma and period keys for switching between brushes, I see that it is swapping between brushes, and not brush SIZES. I may have asked this original question the wrong way , but essentially I need to switch to the last brush size:

[image]

In this photo it shows brush sizes 41 and 18 (shown in red rectangle). This is what I want to toggle. The red underlined part of the photo shows what is being toggled when I use the comma and period keys.

Using Adobe Photoshop Version: 2015.0.0 20150529.r.88 2015/05/29:23:59:59 CL 1024429  x64

Answer (score 2):

You **don't** need shift...

[image]

With the **Brush Tool** active, just hit `,` or `.` to move to the previous/next brush.

I *think* your issue is due to adding the Shift key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I needed to clarify what I am asking, so I edited the question to reflect what I am after. Its really about brush sizes. Have a look at the edited question if you will? THANKS!

Comment: Unfortunately tip *size* is not brush dynamic that's retained. I think you would need to configure *Tool Presets* and toggle those if you want brush tip size to be retained.

Comment: You hopefully are aware, that you can change the brush size very easily by just holding Control+Option (Mac) and then click-drag left or right. (Not sure about the Windows keys) And, of course the `[` and `]` keys.

Comment: @Scott The Windows equivalent for resizing the brush is Alt+left mouse button+drag left/right

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks.. if I were guessing, which I didn't want to do, I'd have guessed alt + right click, drag. Glad you stepped in `:)`

Comment: @Scott yeah, it's a bit of an odd one and not obvious at all, but probably because holding down Alt toggles the Eyedropper tool (while using the Brush) and then right click is used for sampling the colour.